# Performance comparison between using block and Dispose method

Tags: c#, performance, ado.net, try-catch, using-statement

Think about these 2 snippets:

**Approach 1: use `using` statement**

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection())
using(var command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection)){
    try{
        connection.Open();
        using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader(
            CommandBehavior.CloseConnection | CommandBehavior.SingleResult){
            while(reader.Read())
                // read values
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        // log(ex);
    }
}
```

**Approach 2: use `try/finally`**

```
var connection = new SqlConnection();
var command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
SqlDataReader = null;
try{
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader(
        CommandBehavior.CloseConnection | CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
    while(reader.Read())
        // read values...
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    // log(ex);
} finally {
    command.Dispose();
    if (reader != null) {
        if (!reader.IsClosed)
            reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
    }
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

We all know that the `using` statements would be compiled to `try/finally` blocks. So is it correct to say: when the app get compiled, there would be **4** `try` blocks?

```
try { // for using SqlConnection

    try { // for using SqlCommand

        try { // my own try block

            try { // for using SqlDataReader

            } finally { 
                // dispose SqlDataReader
            }

        } catch { 
            // my own catch. can be used for log etc.
        }

    } finally {
        // dispose SqlCommand
    }

} finally {
    // dispose SqlConnection
}
```

And, if the answer is yes, wouldn't that be a performance issue? Generally, is there any, I mean any performance difference between `using` blocks and `try/finally` blocks?

**UPDATE:**

From comments, I've to say:

1- The important question is, having multiple `try` blocks inside each other: is there any performance issue?

2- I have to care of code, because I'm responsible to code, not to query. The query-side has its own developer which is doing his best. So, I have to do my best too. So, it's important to me to take care of milliseconds ;) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really seeing any performance issues? I **can't** believe that the `using` code blocks would be causing performance issues, and would be more inclined to think your query is slow in executing.

Comment: 4 `try/finally` - Yes. Performance problems - No. Why do you asking? Using `using` makes code clean. Use `using`.

Comment: If you're thinking about that level in performance, you shouldn't be using the managed code at all.

Comment: Instead of thinking about the performance impact of `using` you should care about the performance of your query. Your query might run for hours but you're optimizing milliseconds by obfuscating the code.

Comment: Obligatory [performance rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you hear about `try/catch` is slow, it's all about exception handling. So if exception occurs then it might be slow. But just entering in  `try` method is not something you should worry about. Especially in your case when you warp SQL query call.

If you want to know more about exceptions and performance in .NET you can find a lot of articles to read. For example: [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229009(v=vs.100).aspx) or [great CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11265/Performance-implications-of-Exceptions-in-NET).

And of course `using` is preferable way because it makes code much cleaner.

Comment: `Usually when you here about try/catch is slow, it's all about exception handling` good point. I like that +1